# AngularJS Countdown Timer

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the "timer initialized with some predefined end time" found here: http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer.

I got it working on my site, however, I want to remove a DOM element once the timer hits 0. Below is the code that I have:

```
<timer end-time="1451628000000">{{days}} days, {{hours}} hours, {{minutes}} minutes, {{seconds}} seconds.<div ng-if="milleseconds > 0">The countdown has not finished yet!</div></timer>
```

I want the above div to disappear once the milleseconds become 0, because that means the countdown has finished.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could I see your controller code?  do you have a variable called millesconds?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, it looks like milliseconds is represented as `millis`, not `milliseconds`.

Comment: Correct, millis. My bad!

Comment: I can get an ng-show to work, such as this:
    <div ng-show="millis > 0">The countdown has not finished yet!</div>